# How can I find out what is wrong with a SetupDiGetClassDev interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, usb

How do I find out what's wrong with the device info set returned? I'm re-writing my code again and I'm still hitting the same stumbling block.

```
deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref tGuid, 0, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)SetupDiFlags.DIGCF_PRESENT );
if (deviceInfoSet.ToInt32() == INVALID_DEVICE_HANDLE)
{
   int errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
   errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
   statusLabel.Text += "Invalid deviceinfoset returned: " + errCode + " => " + errorMessage + ".";
}
```

The above code doesn't cause any errors but when I use the code below:

```
result = true;
while (result)
{
    result = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoSet, IntPtr.Zero, ref tGuid, Index, ref anInterface);
    if (!result)
    {
        int errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
        statusLabel.Text += "\nSetDiEnumDeviceInterface Error: " + errCode + " => " + errorMessage + ".";
        break;
    }
    Index++;
}
```

to try and access the device info set list, error code 259 (**No more data is available**) is returned. I am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: -1 for a useless subject and continuing your sentence in the body.

Comment: I would really update your question title; it's extremely vague.  Maybe say something like, "USB device programming:  Invalid deviceinfo set."

Comment: I'm sorry P Daddy and Sheepsimulator but I've been going round the same circle for 2 days now trying to figure out what's wrong, so I'm stressed out. I'll make sure to be more descriptive next time.

Comment: it's been 23 minutes and you haven't edited like they suggested. I know you're stressed, but maybe you should, I dunno take a deeeeeep breath and step back a little? Trying to formulate your question *properly* may actually help you solve the issue on your own.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the titles could be edited after post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the right GUID?

Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/doronh/archive/2006/02/15/532679.aspx

Edit:  Everything else looks by-the-book and correct.

Edit2:  Trying including DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE in call to SetupDiGetClassDevs, and see if that works for you.  That is, both DIGCF_PRESENT and DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE.

Edit3:  For the 64bit issue (@Thies), check out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/ea816aea-f718-4a0e-b013-0aa273de037f

Comment: I'm using the Guid returned by the **HidD_GetHidGuid(ref tGuid);** function. SetDiGetClassDevs is returning a deviceinfoset accroding to what is specfied in the parameters. Unfortunately the only way to know whether what is returned is valid is to call the SetupDiEnum* functions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @hythodayr. I am running C# so I could not quite make out the difference required in the C# code given the C(++) example in the post, but need to play with the code when I get more time.

Comment: Oohh thanks.. That seems to have sifted out something from the list. I'll respond later when I've finished chasing this down.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the DIGCF_DEVICEITERFACE flag.. A look through former code showed I had this flag set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this particular interface but it doesn't appear you are doing anything wrong.  It simply appears that you are trying to read data from a device which currently has no data to offer.

Is that the case?  Do you know for sure that the device is currently trying to return data to you?

Comment: According to the msdn spec, SetupDiGetClassDevs (They really need to find a way to shorten these function names) will return a list of devices or an error. At this point I'm not trying to access a device just yet. I'm actually trying to access the list. returned so that I may extract the path for the device needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had simular problems which were due to running on 64-bit Windows. I never quite figured it out, and ended up hardcoding the device path in my code - which is not recommended.

I think it has to do with the API structures not setup correct for 64-bit.

Hope this may help lead someone else to an answer (and maybe help with my problem as well)

Please state if you are running 64-bit - and have you tried the same code on a 32-bit OS?

Comment: My working environment is still 32bit (Win7 RC1). I can say however that using a setupDiGetClassDev + SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo will return a valid deviceinfolist which you can actually query using SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty for a number of things. However using or attempting to use SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail is what derailed me and made me start over again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts with how SetupDiGetClassDevs is called.

If you are looking to get a device path, use SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE ,,,)

SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces fails with error 259 if SetupDiGetClassDevs is given the wrong GUID in ClassGuid which MS Help says is A pointer to the GUID for a device setup class or a device interface class.

Include file devguid.h contains a set of GUID_DEVCLASS values. These are NOT the same as GUID_DEVINTERFACE_* values which are the one you need.

Use #include  which includes ksuuids.h where you'll find GUID_DEVINTERFACE_* values.

There's a more detailed explanation on my website, with some source code that should help in correctly enumerating USB devices.

See http://pixcl.com/SetupDiEnumInterfaces_Fail.htm